# How to change slideshow transition on pause event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'cube',
  /*this is the effect when the slideshow is playing*/
  zoom: true,
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  paginationClickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: 5000,
  preloadImages: true,
  autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
});

function pauseFunction() {
  swiper.stopAutoplay();
  swiper.effect = 'slide' (); /*Here is the effect when user pause the slideshow*/
}

function playFunction() {
  swiper.startAutoplay();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1)"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/2)"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/3)"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/4)"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/5)"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

The pause button is working fine but the effect are not changed at all. Its still using the cube effect. Here is the link to the swiper im using http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WNCd81V97IU. Their forum seems un-active thats why Im seeking help from here.. Thanks! 
Update: Here is the Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hdpb7b91/

Comment: I can see the cube effect, pausing on mouse hover, slide arrows, pagination are working fine. What else do you want do achieve please?

Comment: In my full code i have a pause and play button.. I want the swiper effect to change from 'cube' to 'slide' when user click the pause button.@Inuka

Comment: I've added an answer to your question. Hope it helps. Mark it correct answer if you accept the outcome. Cheers..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is can be seen on below snippet. If you need to restore into the original `cube` effect on play event then reinitialize the slider with original settings.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'cube',
  /*this is the effect when the slideshow is playing*/
  zoom: true,
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  paginationClickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: 5000,
  preloadImages: true,
  autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
});

var activeSlide = swiper.activeIndex;

function pauseFunction() {
  swiper.stopAutoplay();
  activeSlide = swiper.activeIndex;
  swiper.destroy(true, true);
  swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    effect: 'slide',
    /*this is the effect when the slideshow is playing*/
    zoom: true,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    autoplay: 5000,
    preloadImages: true,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
  });
  swiper.slideTo(activeSlide);
}

function playFunction() {
  swiper.startAutoplay();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add action buttons -->
  <br/><br/>
  <button onclick="playFunction()">Play</button>
  <button onclick="pauseFunction()">Pause</button>
</div>
```

**Update 1:** I have modified the answer to accommodate the snippet to revert back to the last active slide after the effect change.

**Update 2:** That awkward auto sliding effect (when on index 4 or 5) can be avoid by adding this `initialSlide: activeSlide` inside the second swiper settings area and commenting out `swiper.slideTo(activeSlide);` line.

Comment: Thanks. But can we do it without the  " swiper.destroy(true, true); " function? Because everytime I pause it the slide goes back to the first page again. Can we make it so that it pause and change effect and stay at the current picture? Thank you for your hardwork and time @Inuka   !

Comment: Hypothetically, if there is a method to record the active slide and set on the re initializing will do the trick. In order to change the effect you have to destroy the existing instance. I must say i haven't used this slider in my projects. So my knowledge is limited but i'll try my best to help you.

Comment: I see. Your answer are giving me more idea now and helping me to understand how it should work. Actually im doing this because the 'zoom' function are not working well if there are effect being set. The zoom function works well with the 'slide' effect but not with other effect. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Thanks! Finally give me the solution for my problem. Although it is a bit long code just for a pause button.. haha.. Thank you so much for your effort. Have a nice day!

Comment: Its all because of this little guy `effect: 'slide'` you wanted. :D Enjoy your solution bud. Happy coding!